# Failed to load resource in assets/templates/name.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku

I have a working copy of an Angular app backed by a Rails app.

I put the Angular templates inside app/assets/templates/devices/ and when I need to use a template, I do it like this:

```
when("/devices", {templateUrl: "assets/devices/select.html", controller: "DevicesListCtrl"})
```

This works fine in my local machine, but when uploading to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Any thoughts on how should I approach this?

I have also tried using the following:

```
//= depend_on_asset devices/index.html
//= depend_on_asset devices/show.html
//= depend_on_asset devices/select.html

window.App = angular.module('TestApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/devices", {templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('assets/devices/index.html') %>", controller: "DevicesListCtrl"}).
    when("/devices/:id", {templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('assets/devices/show.html') %>", controller: "DevicesShowCtrl"}).
    when("/", {templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('assets/devices/select.html') %>", controller: "DevicesSelectCtrl"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/devices'});
}]);
```

But I still get a 404...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you shouldn't add 'assets' in the URL.

Just do this:

```
asset_path('devices/index.html');
```